# Limiting negative peak voltage on ICSP Data lines to less than -0.3V limit under 8kV negative ESD test

Tags: microcontroller, esd, icsp

I am doing ESD simulation using LTSpice for 8kV Negative tests on PGEC & PGED Data lines of PICSP programming port.  am using PIC24FJ256GB406 MCU.  This specifies absolute max negative voltage to -0.3V on these pins. I have tried several ESD and TVS unidirectional diodes.

Under -8kV, the surge current would flow from GND through the forward biased ESD / TVS diode.
I am also using another low Vf diodes between the data lines as steering diodes to Vdd and Vss(GND).  There is a resistor in series with the PGEC and PGCD pins to the RJ11 port. If I increase this R to say 470 ohms, I am able to restrict the negative V on the MCU pins to under -0.3V.

Is this the correct approach to limit the negative voltage on the MCU pins? Is there any other solution?

Comment: See datasheet section 2.5. It seems they aren't very concerned with ESD. It is disturbing that they don't give a kV rating anywhere in the datasheet.

Comment: Hi Tim.  Many thanks for your comments. It is really worrying that they don't seem to be concerned with ESD on ICSP pins.  But I am.  Have so far found that a solution for 8kV negative strike is to use an upfront ESD IC like ESD8008 with 3 lines in parallel for PGEC & PGED port pins limits the negative peak V on the port lines to about -5V.  Then with the use of say 100 ohm series R, will drive the current through a Steering diode with low Vf on the PGEC & PGED pins of the MCU would result in a peak current of about 100mA.  Schottky diodes with Vf of < 300 mV are easy. What do you think?

Comment: Don't worry about a second clamp diode, the first and a series resistor will do.

Comment: I find OnSemi CM1293A-04SO is a good 4 channel steering diode array. Very low cap and Rdyn.  Unfortunately On Semi have only .s2p file for simulation. Do you or anyone knows how can I convert this .s2p file to Spice file that I can use in LTSpice? Some post in another thread suggested adding the .s2p file into \lib\sub folder and add a command line in LT Spice.  Tried that but get an error that this model cannot be found.

Comment: Not in any way that will be useful here. Look, the pins can tolerate some momentary stress outside of abs max ratings. One diode and the resistor is fine, internal ESD diodes handle the rest. I would assume they have a default 1 or 2kV ESD rating... oh here we go: http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/00000169J.pdf 2 it is

Comment: Hi Tim. I have finally decided to use ESD8008 3 ch in parallel at the port and PMEG3002AEL as Steering diodes at the MCU pins for PGEC & PGED.  This gives a safe peak V of around -300mVa for 8kV negative ESD surge.  The costs and pcb sq mm required are low and I can afford this.  A good result in LTSpice enables me not to do actual test but include the simulation results in the Tech Construction file for CE marking.  Have also added on PEMG302 in MCLR to GND t restrict the negative peak.  This may be an over-safe design but I think this is good.  Any comments?

Comment: Will it even program with that much capacitance?

Comment: I had implemented this solution of ESD8008 three lines in parallel + PMEG3002 steering diodes in an earlier project.  This project was implemented and the products posed no issues while programming. We have programmed and tested about 100 of these products.